How to relay and stream HTTP response chunks directly using httpx and FastAPI?
I'm working on a relay handler using httpx and FastAPI to stream HTTP response chunks directly from an upstream server to a client. The goal is to send each chunk of the streamed response directly as it is received, instead of buffering all data and sending it at the end.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Streaming with async generator:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import httpx
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/relay")
async def relay_request():
    try:
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            async with client.stream("POST", relayhandler.url, headers=preparedheaders, json=prepared_request) as response:
                logger.debug(f"Received response with status code {response.status_code}.")

                if response.status_code != 200:
                    response_text = await response.aread()
                    logger.error(f"Relay request failed with status code {response.status_code}: {response_text.decode()}")
                    raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail=response_text.decode())

                async def stream_response():
                    try:
                        async for chunk in response.aiter_bytes():
                            logger.debug(f"Received chunk: {chunk}")
                            yield chunk
                    except httpx.StreamClosed:
                        logger.error("Upstream response stream was unexpectedly closed")
                        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Upstream response stream was unexpectedly closed")

                headers = {
                    "content-type": "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8",
                }

                return StreamingResponse(stream_response(), status_code=response.status_code, headers=headers, media_type="text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8")

    except httpx.RequestError as e:
        logger.error(f"HTTPX Request error: {e}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Unexpected internal server error")

Result: The connection gets closed unexpectedly.

Testing streaming generator directly:
import httpx

timeout = httpx.Timeout(10.0, read=None)  # Set a read timeout to None to allow streaming indefinitely

async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=timeout) as client:
    try:
        stream_gen = stream_response(client, url, headers, payload)
        print("Streaming response:")
        async for chunk in stream_gen:
            print(chunk.decode())
    except httpx.RequestError as e:
        print(f"Request error: {e}")
    except httpx.StreamClosed:
        print("Stream was unexpectedly closed")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")

async def stream_response(client, url, headers, payload):
    async with client.stream('POST', url, headers=headers, json=payload) as response:
        async for chunk in response.aiter_bytes():
            if chunk:
                yield chunk

Result: All the data is collected and then printed at once, not streamed chunk by chunk.

Direct StreamingResponse:
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
    return StreamingResponse(
        client.stream('POST', relayhandler.url, headers=preparedheaders, json=prepared_request),
        status_code=200,
        media_type="text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8"
    )

Result: This raises TypeError: '_AsyncGeneratorContextManager' object is not iterable.

Currently implemented:
async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
    response = await client.post(
        relay_handler.url,
        headers=prepared_headers,
        json=prepared_request,
    )
    logger.debug(f"Received response with status code {response.status_code}.")

    if response.status_code != 200:
        response_text = await response.aread()
        logger.error(f"Relay request failed with status code {response.status_code}: {response_text.decode()}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail=response_text.decode())

    async def stream_response():
        async for chunk in response.aiter_bytes():
            logger.debug(f"Received chunk: {chunk}")
            yield chunk

    headers = {
        "content-type": "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8",
    }

    return StreamingResponse(stream_response(), status_code=response.status_code, headers=dict(headers), media_type="text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8")

Result: It works but it also buffers everything and then streams everything out at once.



Objective:
The ultimate goal is to directly stream every response chunk from the upstream server in a StreamingResponse to the recipient. Can someone help me get this to work correctly?
Environment:

Python 3.9
httpx 0.26.0
FastAPI 0.103.0
Uvicorn 0.20.0

Any help or insights are greatly appreciated!

Does this answer your question?

Related answers might also be found here and here, as well as here and here

With regard to the result of your second code snippet (i.e., "All the data is collected and then printed at once..."), please have a look at this answer as well.

Hey Chris, thanks for your responses. I already had a look at those before I posted, they are also about streaming but not about streaming and relaying directly. I finally found the answer myself.

I finally found the solution:
try:
    async def stream_response():
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            logger.info(f"Relaying request to {relay_handler.url}.")
            async with client.stream('POST', relay_handler.url, headers=prepared_headers, json=prepared_request) as response:
                if response.status_code != 200:
                    response_text = await response.aread()
                    logger.error(f"Relay request failed with status code {response.status_code}: {response_text.decode()}")
                    raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail=response_text.decode())
                
                logger.debug(f"Received response with status code {response.status_code}.")
                async for chunk in response.aiter_bytes():
                    if chunk:
                        logger.debug(f"Received chunk: {chunk.decode()}")
                        yield chunk

    return StreamingResponse(
        stream_response(),
        status_code=200,
        media_type="text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8"
    )
except httpx.RequestError as e:
    logger.error(f"HTTPX Request error: {e}")
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Unexpected internal server error")

So wrapping the entire httpx.AsnyncClient() in the async function stream_response() and yielding from there results in the connection not being terminated anymore once the upstream is done sending and the entire response is streamed correctly downstream. Not 100% smoothly but smooth enough.
